# merge script and value of the buffer in one buffer in C

Tags: c, buffer

I want to send data sensors to server using udp client server.

```
printf("sensor 0 '%s' \n",buf0); 
printf("sensor 1 '%s' \n",buf1);
```

for example the value of the buf0 is 1023 and value of buf1 is 0.
I want to merge sensor 0 :1023 in a buffer say buff

so I can send buff to the server.

and server will receive

```
"sensor 0 :1023"
"sensor 1 :   0"
```

any sugestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)

```
snprintf(buf, 100, "sensor 0 : %s", buf0);
```

where buf is of type `char buf[100];`

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
char buf[128];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "sensor 0: '%s'\n", buf0);
```

etc.